# Are you allowed to use any random DLL file as library?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to create a little program in c# for my fan control and found a dll file in a program of lenovo which has all the methods I need. I have been googling to find out if you are allowed to use any random library for your c# applications but couldn't find an answer. So the question is:

**Are you allowed to use any random DLL file that is on your system or is that plagiarism?**

If it is allowed, is it allowed to publish a program written with it?

If if is not allowed, does this depend on the EULA (if there is one) or is it just generally not allowed?

Kindly regards,
Joris

Comment: There really isn't anything like an "implied" license of usability in any case of software. Most likely you'll have to contact the owner of the library and get permission and a copy of the license the library is released under.

Comment: Plagiarism has nothing to do with binaries. It's copyright that concerns you. There is nothing on your PC that wasn't installed with an EULA or copyright agreement popping up during installation - apart from malware that is. Even dlls that you downloaded from NuGet, SourceForge or GitHub all have a license agreement.

Comment: If you go ahead and use it, you had better keep it to yourself - **completely**. `Lenovo` likely owns and has all rights to the `dll` file you are speaking of, and if you were to release or sell your software, and use their Library in the process, they would likely find you and proceed to call lawyers. Though, this is speculation, as the EULA would indicate who owns and has rights to that library. If you find it you may find your answer.

Comment: @RonBeyer Could you repeat your comment in the answer section? This way I can mark this question as answered and you get the credits. Thank you all  for commenting so quickly, I'll try to get in touch with Lenovo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about legal rights and has nothing to do with any programming issue.

Comment: This could have been on-topic on Programming.SE, except that this is going to be a duplicate there. You don't have a right to Lenovo IP just because the file is named *.DLL. Copyright doesn't work that way. About the only interesting question is whether you can **use** a DLL that you **find** on a system.

Comment: @JorisCoenen Its legal doctrine and I'm more comfortable with a comment than an answer. Thanks though, hopefully Lenovo doesn't have any problems with you using the DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the EULA installed along this library, you MAY or MAY NOT be allowed to **distribute a copy of this library**.

But you can always create a software that **uses this DLL** (i.e. call its functions) and have for requirements that any user of your software should get a copy of the third-party by themselves, for example by installing the same software from Lenovo.

Now if you intend to sell your software, you may need to get an official authorization from Lenovo.

Comment: You may want to provide a source for that last statement. In which law would such an obligation originate?

Comment: This may depend on the State and EULA also.